# la expresión debe tener un tipo de puntero, pero tiene el tipo "int"

Tags: c++, punteros

podrian decirme como podria hacer para que deje de necesitar un puntero o deje de ser un array?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cantidad=0;
    int n = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < cantidad; n++);

    cout << "ingrese que cantidad de numeros desea: ";
    cin >> cantidad;
    
    int v1, v2, producto;
    int par = 0, impar=1;

    par = par + 2;
    v1[n] = par;/me aparece el error aqui
    impar = impar + 2;
    v2[n] = impar;/me aparece el error aqui
    producto = v1 * v2;
    

}
```

Comment: En lugar de colocar texto de relleno que no aporta a tu duda te recomiendo leas [ask], edites y te des el tiempo de explicar a detalle que intentas lograr y que fallo o fallos tiene actualmente tu código

Comment: `v1` lo estas usando como un array y un array trabaja con punteros por eso te da el error y lo mismo para `v2`

Comment: Esta sintaxis no es de `C#` por favor corrige la etiqueta para mejorar las posibilidades de obtener una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, fíjate que estás declarando un bucle basado en `cantidad` antes de inicializar dicha variable. Hay que hacerlo al revés:

```
cout << "ingrese que cantidad de numeros desea: ";
cin >> cantidad;

for (n = 0; n < cantidad; n++);
```

En segundo lugar, nota que tu bucle está mal declarado:

```
for (n = 0; n < cantidad; n++);
```

y lo es por dos razones:

1. Termina en punto y coma, eso hace que el bucle **no haga nada**
2. No tiene llaves. Si no fuese por el primer problema, esto provocaría que el bucle solo ejecutase la primera instrucción que le sigue.

Corregido quedaría así:

```
for (n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
{
    int v1, v2, producto;
    int par = 0, impar=1;

    par = par + 2;
    v1[n] = par;/me aparece el error aqui
    impar = impar + 2;
    v2[n] = impar;/me aparece el error aqui
    producto = v1 * v2;
}
```

Y ahora, tratando el tema de tu pregunta, `v1[n]` solo funcionaría en dos posibles supuestos:

- `v1` es un array
- `v1` es de un tipo de dato que tiene sobrecargado el operador de indexación

No se cumple ninguna de estas condiciones, ya que en tu caso `v1` es de tipo `int`, es decir, almacena un único número entero.

Para crear un array cuyo tamaño esté basado en una variable, en este caso `cantidad`, debes usar `new[]`:

```
int * v1 = new array[cantidad];
```

Puesto todo junto quedaría así:

```
int * v1 = nullptr, * v2 = nullptr;
int par = 0, impar=1;

for (int n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
{
    par = par + 2;
    v1[n] = par;
    impar = impar + 2;
    v2[n] = impar;
    producto = v1[n] * v2[n];
}
```

O también

```
int * v1 = nullptr, * v2 = nullptr;
int par = 0, impar=1;

for (int n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
{
    par += 2;
    v1[n] = par;
    impar += 2;
    v2[n] = impar;
    int producto = v1[n] * v2[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int v1, v2, producto;` estas definiendo v1 como un into cuando en verdad queres un array para poder despues decir `v1[n] = par;`

entonces tenes que definir v1 y v2 asi

`int v1 [5 o el tamano del array que quieras];`
`int v2 [5];`